# Magento: Product Details in popup

Tags: magento-1.9, product, popup, modal-popup

I want to show a product details in popup instead of redirecting to the product view page. How is it possible. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this: https://github.com/czettnersandor/magento-quick-view-ajax

Comment: Not working....

Comment: What do you mean with not working? Does the module not work or doesn't it work as you desired? Does it give you any errors?